# Production a shapefile ID : Big record but small volume

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, vectorization, file-size

How can I generate a shapefile with ArcGIS by converting raster to vector?

My specifications file number when and numerous records but small size and low volume of bytes.

My method was save image of google earth, then

`toolboxes\system toolboxes\3d analyst tools.tbx\raster surface\contour`

and

`interval 0.2` or `0.05` etc.

But unfortunately very big size.

I only want only big record without importance method or figure

Comment: Convert a smaller area, or increase your contour interval.  If you're working in meters or feet, `0.05` is a VERY small interval.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are wanting to do so perhaps a review of these posts may give you some other ideas https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22raster%20to%20polygon%22

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [Raster To Polygon](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm) tool which:

> Converts a raster dataset to polygon features.